# SQL: Return a list of users who visited the same place

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a specific user x, I want to find what other users have visited all the places that user has been to.  To do this I thought I would need to query the same table twice and perform a join to find matching records but so far I have had no luck.

Consider the following simplified table structure:

```
----- VISITATION -----
visitationId        PK
placeId             FK  <-- The place that was visited
userId              FK  <-- The user who visited this place
```

I don't need to extract any information from these foreign tables, for now I just want a list of userId's who visited the same place as user `x`

```
----- RESULT -----
placeId      userId
   1            2
   1            3
   1            1
   4            1
   4            5
   5            8
```

If I was logged in as as user 1, I would expect users 2, 3 and 5 to be returned, 8 would not be returned as he does not have a relation to 1 at a specific place.

To solve this I tried the following query:

```
SELECT x.userId, 
       y.userId 
FROM   visitation x
JOIN
       visitation y
ON 
       y.placeId = x.placeId
WHERE 
       x.userId = 1
GROUP 
   BY  x.userId
```

Currently this only returns `1`, how would I return all of the users who shared the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach.  You can join on the *placeid* and then be sure that all match:

```
select vy.userid
from visitation vx left join
     visitation vy
     on vx.placeid = vy.placeid and vx.userid <> vy.userid
where vx.userid = 1
group by vy.userid
having count(*) = count(vy.placeid);
```

Comment: Yet again Gordon, you've saved me another round of headaches...learning a lot from your answers.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following with the logged in userid as the parameter :userid.

```
SELECT distinct(y.userid)
   FROM visitation x inner join visitation y on x.placed=y.placed
 WHERE x.userid=:userid
```

Comment: Similarly you could add placeid remove the distinct and group by not placeid and userid to get the list of places as well.